# How to get documents that contain certain word in some fields with filtered query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find all books with "Agriculture" category. the books should contain word "paddy" in the title OR abstract field.
Here is my query :

```
GET /books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "abstract": "paddy"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "paddy"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "category": "Agriculture"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

those query return all books with "Agriculture" category, even it's contain word "paddy" or not.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first explain to you how, Your query was fetching all the records, **even it contains word "paddy" or not.** This is b/c you are using the **[should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)** clause which simply means that **The clause (query) should appear in the matching document.** but it means it is not forcing that it **must** appear, hence it's fetching all the documents in your index and then just filtering it on basis of `category`.

What you need is an upper level **must** clause, which means it must appear but then I used nested **should** as it can be either in **title** or **abstract** field, but at least one of these fields must contain the value, so that upper level **must** clause returns true.

The right query is below, which I tried locally and working fine, according to your use case:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "abstract": "paddy"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "title": "paddy"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "category": "agriculture"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it's clear to you and solves your issue.